# NSWindow draw on top of Desktop icons

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, desktop, nswindow

I'm writing an application that is looking to draw a basic NSWindow on top of the Desktop icons (Mac OSX 10.7 Lion).

```
NSWindow *systemInfoWindow  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                                 styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                   backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                     defer:NO];
systemInfoWindow.delegate = self;
[systemInfoWindow setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];

[systemInfoWindow setBackgroundColor:backgroundColorSpace];
[systemInfoWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
[systemInfoWindow setLevel:kCGDesktopIconWindowLevel];
```

This part of code works quite well and the NSWindow gets draw on top of the icons.
But if I switch between two spaces my NSWindow stay behind the icons.

**/* === Update === */**
I think i have problems with my window Level. For better understanding I have uploaded two Screenshots.
Space 1 - window stays like I want on top of the Icons 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1503795/Space1.png

Space 2 - the window is behind the Desktop icons. They should also stay on top
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1503795/Space2.png

A further problem I found. If I activated the App and stay on the first Space and everything looks good like on my first Screenshot. If I select the Files on the Desktop the window also jumps to the back:
*Sorry, can`t post a nother Screenshot*

I hope my problem is a bit more understandably.

I dont`t know how to fix this. Has anybody an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to register for the space change notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter* nc = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
[nc addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(activeSpaceDidChange:) 
    name:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification 
    object:nil];
```

You can then respond to the notification and update your window:

```
- (void) activeSpaceDidChange:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    [[self window] orderFront:self];
}
```

Comment: I like that my window always stay on every space. I think i have problems with my window level. For better understanding I added some more information to my original post.

Comment: Thanks, but now there is an other stange bug.
I made a video, its hard to explain: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1503795/SpaceChange.mpg (7.4 MB)
The first time the window is behind the icons and after a little "shake" the window level fit correctly.

Comment: If I set `[backgroundImageWindow setLevel:kCGDesktopIconWindowLevel+1];` the window stays on top after a space change. But untill this change the window reacted on exposè events. Can I disable that a window listen to exposè events? Thanks for your help! :)